Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML') TypeError: at new Sparkline (sparkline.js)
enter image description here
I am getting above error in my ReactJs Application. The error is occuring in sparkline.js file. I am attaching my whole code of that file. Please look into it and help me solve it.
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like enviroments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    // Browser globals (root is window)
    root.Sparkline = factory();
  }
}(window, function () {
  function extend(specific, general) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var key in general) {
      obj[key] = key in specific ? specific[key] : general[key];
    }
    return obj;
  }

  function Sparkline(element, options) {
    this.element = element;
    this.options = extend(options || {}, Sparkline.options);

    init: {
      this.element.innerHTML = "<canvas></canvas>";
      this.canvas = this.element.firstChild;
      this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
      this.ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

      if (this.options.tooltip) {
        this.canvas.style.position = "relative";
        this.canvas.onmousemove = showTooltip.bind(this);
      }
    }
  }

  Sparkline.options = {
    width: 100,
    height: null,
    lineColor: "black",
    lineWidth: 1.5,
    startColor: "transparent",
    endColor: "black",
    maxColor: "transparent",
    minColor: "transparent",
    minValue: null,
    maxValue: null,
    minMaxValue: null,
    maxMinValue: null,
    dotRadius: 2.5,
    tooltip: null,
    fillBelow: true,
    fillLighten: 0.5,
    startLine: false,
    endLine: false,
    minLine: false,
    maxLine: false,
    bottomLine: false,
    topLine: false,
    averageLine: false
  };

  Sparkline.init = function (element, options) {
    return new Sparkline(element, options);
  };

  Sparkline.draw = function (element, points, options) {
    var sparkline = new Sparkline(element, options);
    sparkline.draw(points);
    return sparkline;
  }

  function getY(minValue, maxValue, offsetY, height, index) {
    var range = maxValue - minValue;
    if (range == 0) {
      return offsetY + height / 2;
    } else {
      return (offsetY + height) - ((this[index] - minValue) / range) * height;
    }
  }

  function drawDot(radius, x1, x2, color, line, x, y) {
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.fillStyle = color;
    this.context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    this.context.fill();
    drawLine.call(this, x1, x2, line, x, y);
  }

  function drawLine(x1, x2, style, x, y) {
    if (!style) return;

    this.context.save();
    this.context.strokeStyle = style.color || 'black';
    this.context.lineWidth = (style.width || 1) * this.ratio;
    this.context.globalAlpha = style.alpha || 1;
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(style.direction != 'right' ? x1 : x, y);
    this.context.lineTo(style.direction != 'left' ? x2 : x, y);
    this.context.stroke();
    this.context.restore();
  }

  function showTooltip(e) {
    var x = e.offsetX || e.layerX || 0;
    var delta = ((this.options.width - this.options.dotRadius * 2) / (this.points.length - 1));
    var index = minmax(0, Math.round((x - this.options.dotRadius) / delta), this.points.length - 1);

    this.canvas.title = this.options.tooltip(this.points[index], index, this.points);
  }

  Sparkline.prototype.draw = function (points) {

    points = points || [];
    this.points = points;

    this.canvas.width = this.options.width * this.ratio;
    this.canvas.style.width = this.options.width + 'px';

    var pxHeight = this.options.height || this.element.offsetHeight;
    this.canvas.height = pxHeight * this.ratio;
    this.canvas.style.height = pxHeight + 'px';

    var lineWidth = this.options.lineWidth * this.ratio;
    var offsetX = Math.max(this.options.dotRadius * this.ratio, lineWidth / 2);
    var offsetY = Math.max(this.options.dotRadius * this.ratio, lineWidth / 2);
    var width = this.canvas.width - offsetX * 2;
    var height = this.canvas.height - offsetY * 2;

    var minValue = Math.min.apply(Math, points);
    var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, points);
    var bottomValue = this.options.minValue != undefined ? this.options.minValue : Math.min(minValue, this.options.maxMinValue != undefined ? this.options.maxMinValue : minValue);
    var topValue = this.options.maxValue != undefined ? this.options.maxValue : Math.max(maxValue, this.options.minMaxValue != undefined ? this.options.minMaxValue : maxValue);
    var minX = offsetX;
    var maxX = offsetX;

    var x = offsetX;
    var y = getY.bind(points, bottomValue, topValue, offsetY, height);
    var delta = width / (points.length - 1);

    var dot = drawDot.bind(this, this.options.dotRadius * this.ratio, offsetX, width + offsetX);
    var line = drawLine.bind(this, offsetX, width + offsetX);

    this.context.save();

    this.context.strokeStyle = this.options.lineColor;
    this.context.fillStyle = this.options.lineColor;
    this.context.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.context.lineCap = 'round';
    this.context.lineJoin = 'round';

    if (this.options.fillBelow && points.length > 1) {
      this.context.save();
      this.context.beginPath();
      this.context.moveTo(x, y(0));
      for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        x += delta;

        minX = points[i] == minValue ? x : minX;
        maxX = points[i] == maxValue ? x : maxX;

        this.context.lineTo(x, y(i));
      }
      this.context.lineTo(width + offsetX, height + offsetY + lineWidth / 2);
      this.context.lineTo(offsetX, height + offsetY + lineWidth / 2);
      this.context.fill();
      if (this.options.fillLighten > 0) {
        this.context.fillStyle = 'white';
        this.context.globalAlpha = this.options.fillLighten;
        this.context.fill();
        this.context.globalAlpha = 1;
      } else if (this.options.fillLighten < 0) {
        this.context.fillStyle = 'black';
        this.context.globalAlpha = -this.options.fillLighten;
        this.context.fill();
      }
      this.context.restore();
    }

    x = offsetX;
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(x, y(0));
    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      x += delta;
      this.context.lineTo(x, y(i));
    }
    this.context.stroke();

    this.context.restore();

    line(this.options.bottomLine, 0, offsetY);
    line(this.options.topLine, 0, height + offsetY + lineWidth / 2);

    dot(this.options.startColor, this.options.startLine, offsetX + (points.length == 1 ? width / 2 : 0), y(0));
    dot(this.options.endColor, this.options.endLine, offsetX + (points.length == 1 ? width / 2 : width), y(points.length - 1));
    dot(this.options.minColor, this.options.minLine, minX + (points.length == 1 ? width / 2 : 0), y(points.indexOf(minValue)));
    dot(this.options.maxColor, this.options.maxLine, maxX + (points.length == 1 ? width / 2 : 0), y(points.indexOf(maxValue)));

    //line(this.options.averageLine, )
  }

  function minmax(a, b, c) {
    return Math.max(a, Math.min(b, c));
  }

  return Sparkline;
}));

While running, I am encountering the error. I attached the image of error. I taken this code from AdminLTE template.
